# Недопустимая длина имени, фамилии и пароля (от 6 до 15 символов)

Tags: php

При Регистрации имени, фамилии, пароля выдает
"Недопустимая длина имени(от 6 до 15 символов)" фамилии и пароля тоже самое выдает введите сюда описание изображения

```html
<?php
    // Получение данных из формы
    $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['surname']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['name']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['pass']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(mb_strlen($name) < 5 || mb_strlen($name) > 15) {
        echo "Недопустимая длина имени (от 6 до 15 символов)";
        exit();
    } else if (mb_strlen($surname) < 5 || mb_strlen($surname) > 15) {
        echo "Недопустимая длина фамилии (от 6 до 15 символов)";
        exit();
    } else if (mb_strlen($pass) < 5 || mb_strlen($pass) > 20) {
        echo "Недопустимая длина пароля (от 6 до 20 символов)";
        exit();
    } 

    $pass = md5($pass."dfgsdfgsdvcxb22");

    // Подключение к базе данных
    require "../blocks/connect.php";
    $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `surname`, `pass`) VALUES('$name', '$surname', '$pass')");

    $mysql->close();

    header('Location: /');
?>
```

```html
<?php
    // Получение данных из формы
    $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['surname']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['pass']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['name']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    
    $pass = md5($pass."dfgsdfgsdvcxb22");

    // Подключение к базе данных
    require "../blocks/connect.php";

    $result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `surname` = '$surname' AND `pass` = '$pass'");
    $user = ($result_set);
    if(count($user) == 0) {
        echo "Такой пользователь не найден";
        exit();
    }

    setcookie('user', $user['name'], time() + 3600, "/");

    $mysql->close();

    header('Location: /');
?>
```

При любом раскладе, при любых данных, выдает ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: имена переменных в первых трех строках кода проверьте.

Comment: Считайте буквы: Константин Устьконстантинопольский https://vk.com/id422071080 Па́бло Дие́го Хосе́ Франси́ско де Па́ула Хуа́н Непомусе́но Мари́я де лос Реме́диос Сиприа́но де ла Санти́сима Тринида́д Ма́ртир Патри́сио Руи́с и Пика́ссо - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE,_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE Александр Белосельский-Белозерский - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%

Answer (score 1):

Возможно этого просто нет в Вашем коде, но Вам необходимо сначала задать параметры элементам вместо `login` на те, которые Вы проверяете:
Проверил у себя - в таком виде всё работает корректно.

```php
<?php
    // Получение данных из формы
    $surname = filter_var(trim($_POST['surname']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $name = filter_var(trim($_POST['name']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pass = filter_var(trim($_POST['pass']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(mb_strlen($name) < 5 || mb_strlen($name) > 15) {
        echo "Недопустимая длина имени (от 6 до 15 символов)";
        exit();
    } else if (mb_strlen($surname) < 5 || mb_strlen($surname) > 15) {
        echo "Недопустимая длина фамилии (от 6 до 15 символов)";
        exit();
    } else if (mb_strlen($pass) < 5 || mb_strlen($pass) > 20) {
        echo "Недопустимая длина пароля (от 6 до 20 символов)";
        exit();
    } 

    $pass = md5($pass."dfgsdfgsdvcxb22");

    // Подключение к базе данных
    require "../blocks/connect.php";
    $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `surname`, `pass`) VALUES('$name', '$surname', '$pass')");

    $mysql->close();

    header('Location: /');
?>
```

Второй файл:

```php
<?php
    // Получение данных из формы
    $surname = filter_var(trim($_POST['surname']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pass = filter_var(trim($_POST['pass']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['name']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $pass = md5($pass."dfgsdfgsdvcxb22");

    // Подключение к базе данных
    require "../blocks/connect.php";

    $result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `surname` = '$surname' AND `pass` = '$pass'");
    $user = ($result_set); // Тут не понятно откуда у Вас берётся переменная $result_set 
    if(count($user) == 0) {
        echo "Такой пользователь не найден";
        exit();
    }

    setcookie('user', $user['name'], time() + 3600, "/");

    $mysql->close();

    header('Location: /');
?>
```

Comment: Можешь ли ты скинуть код как сделать надо ? Пожалуйста.

Comment: @Никита Крайт А вот же в ответе. Обратите внимание на строчки `$surname = filter_var(trim($_POST['surname']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` В них был изменён параметр `login` на необходимый Вам. Первые три строчки просто заменить и  во втором файле.  Это отвечает на Ваш вопрос и будет работать корректно. Как дополнительный совет - Вам лучше сделать запросы в БД через `prepare` или воспользоваться PDO во избежании sql инъекций.

Comment: Спасибо выручил